# How do I load a HigherHRNet in OpenCV C++?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, onnx

I have recently started using the C++ implementation of OpenCV and have been running into a spot of trouble. I have been experimenting with trying to estimate 3D human pose with the video from my built in camera.

To start, I looked at [a project like this](https://github.com/tyIceStream/lightweight-human-pose-estimation.OpenCV) which accomplishes a similar task by importing an ONNX model and loading it with `cv::dnn::readNetFromONNX(modelPath);`. However this model only performs 2D pose estimation. From this I concluded that if I could gather a model from an alternate source and, as long as it was in the ONNX format, then it would be able to be loaded by OpenCV.

I tried going to Google Colab to use OpenVino in a safe environment to grab a copy of the model with [their model downloader and model converter](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/omz_tools_downloader.html). These commands ended up being:

```
!pip install openvino-dev[onnx]
!omz_downloader --name higher-hrnet-w32-human-pose-estimation
!pip install yacs
!omz_converter --name higher-hrnet-w32-human-pose-estimation
```

Through the course of these commands, we see:

```
========== Converting higher-hrnet-w32-human-pose-estimation to ONNX
Conversion to ONNX command: /usr/bin/python3 -- /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/open_model_zoo/model_tools/internal_scripts/pytorch_to_onnx.py --model-path=/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/open_model_zoo/model_tools/models/public/higher-hrnet-w32-human-pose-estimation --model-path=/content/public/higher-hrnet-w32-human-pose-estimation --model-name=get_net --import-module=model '--model-param=file_config=r"/content/public/higher-hrnet-w32-human-pose-estimation/experiments/higher_hrnet.yaml"' '--model-param=weights=r"/content/public/higher-hrnet-w32-human-pose-estimation/ckpt/pose_higher_hrnet_w32_512.pth"' --input-shape=1,3,512,512 --input-names=image --output-names=embeddings,heatmaps --output-file=/content/public/higher-hrnet-w32-human-pose-estimation/higher-hrnet-w32-human-pose-estimation.onnx

ONNX check passed successfully.

========== Converting higher-hrnet-w32-human-pose-estimation to IR (FP16)
Conversion command: /usr/bin/python3 -m mo --framework=onnx --data_type=FP16 --output_dir=/content/public/higher-hrnet-w32-human-pose-estimation/FP16 --model_name=higher-hrnet-w32-human-pose-estimation --reverse_input_channels '--input_shape=[1,3,512,512]' --input=image '--mean_values=image[123.675,116.28,103.53]' '--scale_values=image[58.395,57.12,57.375]' --output=embeddings,heatmaps --input_model=/content/public/higher-hrnet-w32-human-pose-estimation/higher-hrnet-w32-human-pose-estimation.onnx
```

which indicates the existence of `higher-hrnet-w32-human-pose-estimation.onnx` in our local storage. So I downloaded that file to my local device and ran in the above context. When I run, I get a cryptic error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFB62FF4F69 in posedetect.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location
```

Is there a way to load a 3D pose estimation model in OpenCV using C++?

---

**Alternate attempt with openpose**

I tried following the recommendation for using openpose as an alternative to the HigherHRNet model as described by @B200011011 is the comments. To do this I went to the [open pose github](https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose) and performed the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose.git
cd openpose/models
getModels.bat
cp pose/body_25/pose_iter_584000.caffemodel ../source/repos/posedetect/models/
```

When I try to load this caffe model with `cv::dnn::readNetFromCaffe(modelPath);` I get a similar cryptic error as trying to load the HigherHRNet Model:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFB62FF4F69 in posedetect.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000E42CB0D660.
```

So how do I load a HigherHRNet (or other 3D pose estimation) model in OpenCV C++?

Comment: Openpose has c++ api and 3d keypoints, https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose. Openpose caffe models can be loaded into opencv dnn.

Comment: I have updated the original question to include attempting a model from openpose. The attempt resulted in a similar error.

Comment: i'm quite sure, that the caffe model needs a corresponding prototxt

Comment: I have more adjustments to make to confirm that everything works, but including the prototxt for the caffe model at least makes it past the point where the model loads.

Comment: can you try [one of the proven working models](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/samples/dnn/openpose.cpp) ?

Comment: These models appear to work correctly. I can accept this as an answer if you write it as one. Any details on why the onnx model from openvino did not work would be appreciated even though I do not need them for my goals.

Comment: The very first step is to at least point what's the line of code that generates the exception. Is the exception thrown when the model is loaded? during inference? While pre-processing the input image? ...